# Interpretation of Force/Torque Sensor using gazebo_ros_ft_sensor plugin

Tags: ros, force, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've successfully added a force torque/sensor to my model by adding following codes in my urdf file:

```
<gazebo reference="shoulder_pan_joint">
    <provideFeedback>true</provideFeedback>
</gazebo>


<gazebo>
    <plugin name="ft_sensor" filename="libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so">
        <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
        <topicName>ft_sensor_topic</topicName>
        <jointName>shoulder_pan_joint</jointName>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Although the model is static and nothing is moving in gazebo gui, the outputs of force/torque sensor published by "ft_sensor_topic" is fluctuating. For example the force value that I expect to be -100 is fluctuating between -55 N and -143N. Other 5 components of torque and force values are also fluctuating in a similar range.

I also tried to reduce Gaussian Noise of the sensor by adding  `<gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>`  to the plugin tag. but this didn't solve the problem.

I'm using gazebo 2.2.3 + Ros indigo running in ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243173/interpretation-of-force/torque-sensor-using-gazebo_ros_ft_sensor-plugin/) by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realize this is an old post, however I found that the torque/force plugin for gazebo was giving very large values even when my model was stationary. Generating better inertial values made the reported values much better (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4372/the-inertia-matrix-explained)

---

Originally posted by [KurtR](https://answers.ros.org/users/36914/kurtr/) with karma: 16 on 2018-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1